# How to break C# GUI label text into separate lines (Not in runtime)?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, text, label

Breaking the display text of a C# Windows Form Application's label using codes are as easy as:

```
lblDisplay.Text = "Line1 \n Line2";
```

But if we want the display text of the label to be in 2 separate line before runtime (while designing). How do we do it using the properties window of the label and **not using any coding** to do it?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the property value for Text, click the down arrow to open up the multi-line string editor. Use the enter key to insert a new line where necessary.

[image: Properties window]

Which results in a multi-line label:

[image: Form]

Comment: Can we do that for a label?

Comment: `+1` and `Ans Accepted`